# Multiple newsletter lists possible?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, newsletter

I have 2 store views, 1 in dutch and 1 in english

As far as i can tele magento offers only 1 subscription option

anyway, we would like to use mailchimp for newsletter sending

i was hoping to be able to set a newsletter subscription for the dutch store view and one for the english store view and than use magemonkey from ebizmart to sync it all

Is that possible?

Or would i better create the lists i need in Mailchimp, get the code for the subscription and paste that in a block for each store view (and of course turn newsletter in magento off)

any advise?

thanks

Comment: Carlo, for sure you can use MageMonkey to do what you need. Please note that the extension is free of charge and support is also free -forums based-.

Comment: Yep, i asked them a few questions and they helped me understand! Great!

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of magento mailchimp implementations our there. I'm sure one of them solves your problem.

And yes, of course do you maintain the lists in mailchimp! :-)